# Weird canvas result in my Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am currently trying to create a Tic Tac Toe game.

When I run it the drawings on the canvas get totally messed up. The circles are not drawn until the next cross is drawn and there are weird lines between the crosses and the circles. (Tried to post picture, but need 10 rep)

I have no idea why this is happening, but I know the problem is somewhere in the drawing process.

```
function drawIt(w, h, p) {
    //w is the x coordinates for the square where it is supposed to draw
    //the h is the y coordinates and p is just the number of the square
    if (turn == 0 && !pressed[p]) {
        ctx.moveTo(w, h);
        ctx.lineTo(w + (width / 3), h + (height / 3));
        ctx.moveTo(w + (width / 3), h);
        ctx.lineTo(w, h + (height / 3));
        ctx.stroke();
        turn = 1;
        pressed[p] = true;
    } else if (turn == 1 && !pressed[p]) {
        ctx.arc(w + (width / 6), h + (height / 6), width / 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        //width and height is just the width and the height of the canvas
        ctx.stroke;
        turn = 0;
        pressed[p] = true;
    } else if (pressed[p]) {
        alert("!!!");
    }
}
```

I'm new to javascript so all help is much appreciated.

Comment: you mean edit the question you already have?

Comment: Learn to use your browser's development tools. It's the best way to learn how your code is running and to debug too.

Comment: Up voted so you will have 10 rep and can post pic of what's happening.

Comment: Please post an embeddable direct link to the image - someone with more rep can edit it in for you

Comment: http://oi41.tinypic.com/1dy736.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second ctx.stroke is missing the brackets, so it won't draw the circle.  But the circle has been added to the open path, and is therefore drawn when you later call ctx.stroke()

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ctx.beginPath() each time you begin a path.
Otherwise draws will just pile up.

Comment: Tried it, now the circles never appears